# How to send info to a PHP script with AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, get

I cannot get my simple ajax script to run. The code should be pretty simple.
The ajax script is:

```
<html>

<head><title>Testing ajax</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ajax() {

            var xmlhttp;

            var fname=document.getElementById("fname").value;

            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

                }

            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?fname="+fname,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>


    <form>

        <input type="text" id="fname">

        <input type="text" id="lname">

        <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="ajax()">


    </form>


    <div id="output"></div>


</body>
```

And the php script is:

```
<?php

$fname=$_GET['fname'];

echo "<p>Hello ".$fname."</p>";

?>
```

I have also tried:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/pass-data");
xmlhttp.send("fname="+fname);
```

I can't get neither post not get method to send data. Am I not seeing something simple?

Comment: You're posting the data but trying to retrieve it in php from $_GET?

Comment: I've tried both post and get but cannot get either way to work. Right it is using get

Comment: is the JS file located in the same folder as the PHP file? The path is  correct?

Comment: Yeah, they're both in the same folder and i copy and pasted the file name to make sure that was right too.

Comment: @EricLarsen fyi, when you're not sure whether a piece of information will be sent via POST or GET, you can use $_REQUEST. It contains all values from both $_POST and $_GET. Probably better not to do this if it's not necessary, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is not working is due to the fact that you have your inputs inside of `<form>` tags.  After removing the form tags, when I tried your code with the `<input type="submit" />` control changed to

```
<input type="button" onClick="ajax()" value="Submit" />
```

it worked like a charm.  I suspect that form behaviour is handled differently due to certain benefits when submitting, security concerns, and such.

Answer (score 0):

Change the input type from submit to button

input type="button" onclick=...

because when you click the button it will right away submit the page if the type="submit".